# The problem of not converging when Keras versions are different

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I implemented ResNet in Keras/TF' two versions (TF 2.0.8, TF 2.1.4 ).

Older versions (TF 2.0.8) converged (5 out of 5 times).

However, it did not converged in the latest version (TF2.1.4).

The source code is exactly the same. Why does this problem occur?

```
extractor_feature_model = tf.keras.applications.ResNet50V2(
include_top=False,
weights=None,
input_tensor=None,
input_shape=am.input_shape,
pooling="avg"
)
estimation_model = am.build_estimation_model_eul(_input_shape=extractor_feature_model.output.shape[1:])
trainer_model = am.concat_model(extractor_feature_model, estimation_model)
opt = keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=1e-4)
trainer_model.compile(loss=au.Custom_EUL_Loss(), optimizer=opt)
trainer_model.summary()
trainer_model.fit(train_x, train_y)
```

Comment: I recommend you to check the release notes for keras between those 2 versions. Algorithms can change.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. The override destination (inheritance destination) of the custom loss function was changed from release notes, so this has been addressed. This error also occurs even if I use the general MSE in keras. I also experimented by reinstalling Keras and TF many times. It seems that it no longer converges from 2.0.9 onwards.